# With a hundred inches of ink I draw a square and a circle so that the sum of the areas is a minimum.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

“With a hundred inches of ink I draw a square and a circle so that the sum of the areas is a minimum. What is the length of the perimeter of the square? (Hint: Find the area as a function of p. Expect about a dozen lines of computation.)”

I know the answer is 400/(π+4), but I have no idea how to get there. I’ve been working for two hours but I don’t seem to be getting any closer.

Comment: Suppose the amount of ink used for the circle is $x$.  Then the amount used for the square is $100-x$.  Since $x$ is the circumference of the circle, its area must be $\frac1{4\pi} x^2$.  Since $100-x$ is the perimeter of the square, its area must be $\frac1{16}(100-x)^2$.  Do you have this?

Comment: Consider writing the equations for perimeter and area with respect to the radius of the circle and the length of the side of a square (i.e. two formulas with respect to $x$ and $r$). If you can do that, you'll be on your way.

Comment: Where does the 1/16 come from? Maybe I’m just dumb, but I don’t understand how to rewrite the equations. ‍♂️

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximize and Minimize a 12" piece of wire into a square and circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52200/maximize-and-minimize-a-12-piece-of-wire-into-a-square-and-circle)

Comment: I understand the 1/16 now, but I’m still not getting 400/(π+4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s$ be the length of the side of the square, and $r$ the radius of the circle. You know that 
$$
4s+2\pi r=100. 
$$
And you want to minimize
$$
s^2+\pi r^2=s^2+\pi\left( \frac{100-4s}{2\pi}\right)^2=s^2+\frac{(50-2s)^2}{\pi}.
$$
If you differentiate with respect to $s$ and equate to zero, you get (after dividing by $2$)
$$
s-\frac{2(50-2s)}\pi=0.
$$
Solving for $s$, we get
$$
s=\frac{100}{\pi+4}.
$$
So that's the side of the square. To get the perimeter of the square, multiply by $4$.

We can confirm that this is a minimum either by checking the second derivative, or by noticing that we were minimizing a parabola, where there is a single critical point.

Comment: Why does 4s + 2r = 400? 4s = the square’s perimeter. 2r = the circle’s perimeter. According to the question, the perimeter of the square plus the perimeter of the circle equals 100 inches of ink. Am I missing something?

Comment: I misresd. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: And then, of course, there's the classic follow-up: what's the perimeter of the square which maximizes the sum of the areas ... .

Comment: Thank you so much! 